# on version 18.04 i3wm have problem binding Keypads

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, i3-wm

i use i3wm as a graphical interface, and i use for example $mod+KP_1 to change to workspace 1, but when i upgraded to Xubuntu 18.04, this binding doesn't work anymore.i am unable to bind any KP_x to any command.i tried this with bindsym and bindcode, same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently switched to i3 and had the same problem. Not sure exactly why it happens but it was the topic of [this](https://github.com/i3/i3/issues/2558) github issue here. It is since closed but the issue persists. However the suggestion at the bottom of the issue thread works for me. Here is the related lines from my config:

```
# Switch with numpad
    bindsym $mod+Mod2+KP_1 workspace $ws1
    bindsym $mod+Mod2+KP_2 workspace $ws2
    bindsym $mod+Mod2+KP_3 workspace $ws3
    bindsym $mod+Mod2+KP_4 workspace $ws4
    bindsym $mod+Mod2+KP_5 workspace $ws5
    bindsym $mod+Mod2+KP_6 workspace $ws6
    bindsym $mod+Mod2+KP_7 workspace $ws7
    bindsym $mod+Mod2+KP_8 workspace $ws8
    bindsym $mod+Mod2+KP_9 workspace $ws9
    bindsym $mod+Mod2+KP_0 workspace $ws10

# move with numpad
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_End move container to workspace $ws1
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_Down move container to workspace $ws2
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_Next move container to workspace $ws3
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_Left move container to workspace $ws4
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_Begin move container to workspace $ws5
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_Right move container to workspace $ws6
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_Home move container to workspace $ws7
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_Up move container to workspace $ws8
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_Prior move container to workspace $ws9
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_Insert move container to workspace $ws10
```

Comment: That works! Thank you
i think this is due to having Mod2=NumLock, so when i press a keypad i must indicate that a numlock is activated.
this is still strange because i didn't face this problem before